# Pandas: logical and of two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes which have boolean entries

[image: df1]

[image: df2]

How do I perform a **logical and** on the corresponding values?

**Desired result:**

[image: desired result]

Comment: Can you just do `df1 & df2`?

Comment: What bias do you have True or False..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((True, False), (5, 3)),
                   pd.date_range('2016-06-06', '2016-06-10'), list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((True, False), (5, 3)),
                   pd.date_range('2016-06-06', '2016-06-10'), list('ABC'))

df1
```

[image]

```
df2
```

[image]

```
df1 & df2
```

[image]